# Playing audio after Activity transition is complete

Tags: android, audio, animation, android-activity

I am writing an Activity. It is supposed to display some view and play a sound. Everything is great, except for... 
I am not sure where to put the code to play sound. 
Currently I am playing it in `onCreate()` method of Activity, but the sound starts playing before Activity transition is complete. I would very much like the sound to play after the transition is complete and entire view is visible.
Is there any method that I can override/any Listener that I can implement, that gets called after the transition is complete? Is there any way to know the duration of transition, so I can simply `postDelayed(Runnable action, long delayMillis)` on View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to put your code for playing sound in `onResume()`? Because it gets called when Activity is in foreground.

From Docs,

**onResume() -**

> Called after onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle), onRestart(), or
>   onPause(), for your activity to start interacting with the user. This
>   is a good place to begin animations, open exclusive-access devices
>   (such as the camera), etc

Comment: onResume is called when the Activity is visible, not when the transition has ended. you can test this with a custom transition that has a duration with lets say 5 seconds...